# Is there a Windows Live Messenger mobile app for WP7?

Tags: windows-live, messenger

I am looking for a WP7 mobile app to connect to Windows Live Messenger.  All my Google searches of "windows live messenger mobile app" ultimately end up leading me right to this page:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/hotmail/mobile

This appears to be for Hotmail email, though.  Is there a WP7 app that lets me connect to Live Messenger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Messenger is being retired I doubt it.

Messenger is being merged with Skype, under the Skype name now. So you could download the Skype app.

Here is an email (dated January 10, 2013) I got from Microsoft:

> Hello,
>
> We are retiring the existing Messenger service globally (except for
>   mainland China where Messenger will continue to be available) and
>   bringing the great features of Messenger and Skype together. Update to
>   Skype and sign in using a Microsoft Account (same as your Messenger
>   ID) and all your Messenger contacts will be at your fingertips. You'll
>   be able to instant message and video chat with them just like before,
>   and also discover new ways of staying in touch with Skype on your
>   mobile and tablet.
>
> Yours sincerely,
>    The Messenger Team
>       **So, what's happening between
>   now and the retirement?**
>    Messenger will continue to work as you know
>   it today. If you are signed in with Messenger on your desktop** you
>   will see a banner notification to upgrade. When you click on the
>   banner, an installer window will open with the request to upgrade.
>   This will take you through our installer flow to install Skype and
>   automatically uninstall Messenger.  space  
> **So, what's happening after
>   the retirement?**
>    Messenger users on desktops will not be able to
>   sign in and will only be able to upgrade to Skype. If you attempt to
>   sign in, a notification will appear, and if you continue, you will be
>   taken through our installer flow to install Skype and automatically
>   uninstall Messenger at the same time.  space  
> **Can I update to Skype on
>   my mobile?**
>    Yes! Skype is available on iPhone, Android and soon on
>   Windows Phone 8. We encourage you to download the latest Skype app on
>   your mobile and then uninstall Messenger. You will be able to sign in
>   to Skype on your iPhone, Android and Windows Phone 8 mobile apps with
>   your Microsoft Account over the next few weeks. If you use another
>   phone with Messenger on it, it will continue to work for a while.

Comment: It is my understanding that the *Windows client* is being retired, as well as the brand name; The Windows Skype client now allow interactions with those still on Messenger, which would be pointless if the whole thing was going. As @jumbo said in his answer, the basic functionality is built into Windows Phone 7.x, so *no app is required*

Comment: The service will be retired eventually. Not March 31st, but eventually. For now you can use the functionality in the phone, but you might as well get used to Skype chat because that's what you'll end up using when the service goes away.

Answer (score 4):

I think that with Windows Phone 7, you don't need a special app for Windows Live Messenger chat, because this channel was integrated into OS.

You can go into **Settings->email+accounts->add an account** and add your Live account here (if it is not already there). And then you go into **Messages** and slide the pivot screen to the left or right. There you see your online contacts from all account you have added in settings (i.e. facebook, live messenger). You can start chatting from there.

But it is true that Microsoft won't continue with Live Messenger (as Louis answered).

Comment: Additionally, you cat "set chat status" using the "Me" tile, which sets it on supported networks. (Worth noting that it supports more than just Messenger)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Live Messenger is on it's way out, and it's already integrated into WP7.5
However, there was a third-party Live Messenger app available before 7.5 came out, called "Messenger by Miyowa". I just checked, and it's still on the marketplace.

Comment: That app was unusably buggy. I installed it before WP7 had the built in functionality, and uninstalled it pretty much immediately.

Comment: It wasn't fantastic at the start, but greatly improved as updates rolled out. To be fair, it was better than nothing, seeing as M$ hadn't even bothered to include their own chat service in WP7!